# Disable exception handling in Acceleo engine

Tags: java, eclipse, acceleo

In Acceleo, when I edit and save, say, `generate.mtl`, Acceleo automatically generates `Generate.java` class. From this java class I can call `doGenerate` method from an external class to generate my model-based stuff.

However, if there is some exception during execution, this exception is handled by the Acceleo engine. **I would like to tell Acceleo engine not to handle exceptions**, and thus realize that an error occurred.
How is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've been thinking for a long time about this, without success. Last week, I successfully ran Acceleo in standalone mode, from a Java class instead of using the pluging.

It made me spend a lot of time with issues with libraries, problems with dependencies etc. but I finally got it (I mean, it's a hard work, be patient).

My surprise: When I ran Acceleo standalone it failed, but the templates were the same. I was having many errors, but the plugin was managing then and the plugin was printing an empty String as a result! Running Acceleo standalone, those errors raise an exception and my main class prints the stacktrace.

So, if you want to manage the errors by yourself, I recommend you to run it standalone but... good luck! :)

I hope this would help you :)

Comment: hi! I actually run Acceleo standalone. Like you, it was a really hard hard work to make all working standalone.

However, my problem is that I integrated the Acceleo engine into a software, then I need to notice Acceleo error to notify the user that the process failed.

Thanks anyway